# UPDATE de campo de tabla con resultados de una consulta

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-12

yo creo que debe ser sencillo, pero se me esta atravesando.

Dispongo de una tabla "A"(3500 lineas) con el campo "id" Autonumerico y campo "id_responsable" actualmente en NULL, que tengo que rellenar con los valores de una consulta "B"(324 lineas) que me devuelve los campos "id" e "id_responsable".

Tengo también una consulta "C" con los ids que necesito actualizar para la clausula where del UPDATE FROM:(326 lineas)

Busco actualizar las lineas de los ids de la tabla "A" que coincidan con los ids de la consulta "B" con el campo id_responsable de la consulta "B".

Basándome en esta estructura:

```
UPDATE
    Table_A
SET
    Table_A.col1 = Table_B.col1,
    Table_A.col2 = Table_B.col2
FROM
    Some_Table AS Table_A
    INNER JOIN Other_Table AS Table_B
        ON Table_A.id = Table_B.id
WHERE
    Table_A.col3 = 'cool'
```

No consigo que me actualice correctamente los campos de A, con los datos de la consulta B en los ids coincidentes, terminan actualizándose TODAS las lineas de la Tabla "A" con
un único "id_responsable" de la tabla "B", actualizando 3500 lineas de al tabla A, en ved de como máximo 326 lineas.

RESULTADOS A 3500 lineas (pro.proyecto)
id|id_responsable_proto

RESULTADOS consulta B 324 Lineas con datos de id_responsable (lineas de esos proyectos donde hago select del id_responsable)
id|id_responsable_proto

RESULTADOS consulta C 326 Lineas a modificar (quedaran dos lineas a null que no se encuentran en consulta B)
id

En que puedo estar equivocándome? Las consultas individualmente me ofrecen las lineas que os comento..pero me actuliza todas las lineas de "A" con un único valor de "B"

Mi codigo:

```
    UPDATE
    pro.proyecto  --(A) -- 3500lineas
SET
    id_responsable_proto = h.id_responsable_proto --(B)
FROM
    pro.proyecto AS Table_A
    INNER JOIN ( --324 lineas
        SELECT h.id_proyecto as id, h.id_empleado as id_responsable_proto FROM(
    (SELECT DISTINCT ON(d.id_proyecto) d.id_proyecto,
    CASE WHEN desarrollo.id_empleado IS NOT NULL THEN desarrollo.id_empleado ELSE
    CASE WHEN prototipo.id_empleado IS NOT NULL THEN prototipo.id_empleado ELSE
    CASE WHEN madera_acrilico.id_empleado IS NOT NULL THEN madera_acrilico.id_empleado ELSE
    CASE WHEN presupuesto.id_empleado IS NOT NULL THEN presupuesto.id_empleado END END END
    END as id_empleado,
    CASE WHEN desarrollo.semana IS NOT NULL THEN desarrollo.semana ELSE
    CASE WHEN prototipo.semana IS NOT NULL THEN prototipo.semana ELSE
    CASE WHEN madera_acrilico.semana IS NOT NULL THEN madera_acrilico.semana ELSE
    CASE WHEN presupuesto.semana IS NOT NULL THEN presupuesto.semana END END END
    END as semana
FROM tar.tarea d
    LEFT JOIN tar.tarea desarrollo ON (desarrollo.id_proyecto = d.id_proyecto  AND desarrollo.id_secci = 3)
    LEFT JOIN tar.tarea prototipo ON (prototipo.id_proyecto = d.id_proyecto AND (prototipo.id_secci = 2 OR prototipo.id_secci = 73))
    LEFT JOIN tar.tarea madera_acrilico ON (madera_acrilico.id_proyecto = d.id_proyecto AND (madera_acrilico.id_secci=49 OR madera_acrilico.id_secci=50))
    LEFT JOIN tar.tarea presupuesto ON (presupuesto.id_proyecto = d.id_proyecto  AND (presupuesto.id_secci = 40 OR presupuesto.id_secci = 71))
WHERE  prototipo.id_proyecto=d.id_proyecto OR d.id_proyecto= madera_acrilico.id_proyecto OR d.id_proyecto= desarrollo.id_proyecto 
OR d.id_proyecto= presupuesto.id_proyecto)
)h WHERE id_proyecto IN ((SELECT id FROM pro.proyecto_con_cliente_sector_estado_presu__vista AS t WHERE 1 = 1 
AND (id_estado <> 2 AND id_estado <> 4)        
AND (tareas_presupuesto > 0) OR presupuestos > 0))) AS h
        ON Table_A.id = h.id
WHERE --(C) //326 lineas
    h.id IN ((SELECT id FROM pro.proyecto_con_cliente_sector_estado_presu__vista AS t WHERE 1 = 1 
AND (id_estado <> 2 AND id_estado <> 4)        
AND (tareas_presupuesto > 0) OR presupuestos > 0))
```

Actualiza 3500 lineas en ved de 324/326.

Gracias

Comment: La consulta es más compleja de lo que nos cuentas al principio (hay más `JOIN` en el segundo bloque de código). Convendría que nos muestres un [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com) con un pequeño set de datos donde se reproduzca el problema que planteas en la pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Al final era mas facil de lo que pensaba, con una subconsulta simple salió.

```
    UPDATE pro.proyecto
    SET id_responsable_proto = t2.id_responsable_proto --(B)
    FROM (
            SELECT h.id_proyecto, h.id_empleado as id_responsable_proto FROM(
                (SELECT DISTINCT ON(d.id_proyecto) d.id_proyecto,
                    CASE WHEN desarrollo.id_empleado IS NOT NULL THEN desarrollo.id_empleado ELSE
                    CASE WHEN prototipo.id_empleado IS NOT NULL THEN prototipo.id_empleado ELSE
                    CASE WHEN madera_acrilico.id_empleado IS NOT NULL THEN madera_acrilico.id_empleado ELSE
                    CASE WHEN presupuesto.id_empleado IS NOT NULL THEN presupuesto.id_empleado END END END
                    END as id_empleado,
                    CASE WHEN desarrollo.semana IS NOT NULL THEN desarrollo.semana ELSE
                    CASE WHEN prototipo.semana IS NOT NULL THEN prototipo.semana ELSE
                    CASE WHEN madera_acrilico.semana IS NOT NULL THEN madera_acrilico.semana ELSE
                    CASE WHEN presupuesto.semana IS NOT NULL THEN presupuesto.semana END END END
                END as semana
                FROM tar.tarea d
                LEFT JOIN tar.tarea desarrollo ON (desarrollo.id_proyecto = d.id_proyecto  AND desarrollo.id_secci = 3)
                LEFT JOIN tar.tarea prototipo ON (prototipo.id_proyecto = d.id_proyecto AND (prototipo.id_secci = 2 OR prototipo.id_secci = 73))
                LEFT JOIN tar.tarea madera_acrilico ON (madera_acrilico.id_proyecto = d.id_proyecto AND (madera_acrilico.id_secci=49 OR madera_acrilico.id_secci=50))
                LEFT JOIN tar.tarea presupuesto ON (presupuesto.id_proyecto = d.id_proyecto  AND (presupuesto.id_secci = 40 OR presupuesto.id_secci = 71))
                WHERE  prototipo.id_proyecto=d.id_proyecto OR d.id_proyecto= madera_acrilico.id_proyecto OR d.id_proyecto= desarrollo.id_proyecto 
                OR d.id_proyecto= presupuesto.id_proyecto)
                )h WHERE id_proyecto IN ((SELECT id FROM pro.proyecto_con_cliente_sector_estado_presu__vista AS t WHERE 1 = 1 
                AND (id_estado <> 2 AND id_estado <> 4)AND (tareas_presupuesto > 0) OR presupuestos > 0))
        ) t2
WHERE id =t2.id_proyecto;
```

Esto funciona de maravilla, no se porque me compliqué tanto. Gracias